Governance execute proposal of the governance contract itself or any other contract or restrict functions to come from a proposal only in the erc20
Is it possible to have a proposal that executes a function from the governance contract itself?
namely i would like to have every expense of the dao to come from a proposal.
does the target have to be an erc20 or could it be the governance contract itself or any other not erc20 contract. namely i would like to collect eth from the sell of an erc20 and have every expense to come from a proposal, otherwise would it be possible to restrict an erc20 contracts function to come only from the governance contract executed proposals? Or could a govenors contract also execute functions of not an erc20 contract but something different?
